# Files app and all files and folders are not showing up in 23.10 version after reboot

Tags: gdm, 23.10

I've run into a problem where the Files app in Ubuntu doesn't show, and even all of my folders and files are hidden from the display screen; even searching in the search box doesn't show them. I tried to `ls` if the file and folder exist, and it does, but when I tried to download a file, the files app opened to save a file, which means it does exist. Could anyone help me with this?

What I did before the issue:
I ran into a boot issue (due to the installation of the fuse in 23.10), so as instructed in the solution, I clicked `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F3` and from there, I did below:

```bash
sudo apt purge fuse
sudo apt-purge gdm3
sudo apt install gdm3
```

This method worked, and I rebooted, but currently I'm unable to see the files, apps, and other files and folders. I believe the issue happened because of `gdm3` since it's the display manager, so could anyone please help me? Thank you for your time; I really appreciate it.